# Clarify me how to pass an argument through String args

Tags: java, eclipse

I start saying that my IDE is eclipse. I was trying to do a program that should find the phone number of a specific person through the name. This is the code

```
class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        String numbers[][] = {
                {"Tom", "555-3322"},
                {"Mary", "555-8976"},
                {"Jon", "555-1037"},
                {"Rachel", "555-1400"},
        };
        int i;

        if(args.length != 1)
            System.out.println("Usage: java Phone <name>");
        else {
            for(i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
                if(numbers[i][0].equals(args[0])) {
                    System.out.println(numbers[i][0] + ": " + numbers[i][1]);
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i == numbers.length)
                System.out.println("Name not found");
        }
          }
        }
```

I found that in some forums that to make work it I have to go to run -> run configuration -> arguments. Hence I set the program argument to "Mary" and the output was the right one, that showed me the name (Mary) and the phone number (555-8976). Is this the right way or is there a better one?

Comment: That is a perfectly acceptable way to run it. The other common way would be via the [command line](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-command-line-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing the argument passing is fine, but sometimes it's better to ask yourself which is the best option to do something in general, instead of just sticking with an idea and ask how to take that idea in particular to the real world.

To perform this type *key-value* operation, I recommend using a HashMap. If you don't know about them, that's OK, there are other ways to do what you want. I highly recommend learning about them though, because they make these kind of tasks really easy.

Basically, a HashMap is an object that has values stored in it and to access them you need to specify a key. For example:

**Key -------Value**

Name:    --  "Mary"

Number:    "12335635"

Age: -----"64"

Keep in mind all the keys have to be the same type(generally we use String) and the values should also be of the same type, that's why I put the numbers inside quotes. Maybe this example isn't the best one but the key type and the value type doesn't have to be the same. You can have your keys be Strings and your values be int.

I recommend this post: [HashMap in Java with Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java-with-examples/) and of course, the Java Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code at present works fine with run-time arguments, as you have seen while using a run-config setup in your IDE. You could also just compile this on the command-line (without an IDE) and then execute `java Phone Mary`.

If you wish to solicit interactive user input (as opposed to run-time arguments) you would have to refactor using something like `Scanner`.

Comment: I'm not understanding how to put java Phone Mary, since is all in a quote it shouldn't notice it and simply display java Phone Mary, could you please explain?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html